# Kotlin - TypeCastException on view.getTag()

Tags: android, kotlin

I have got a class called ItemClickSupport that attaches an ItemClick to a RecyclerView:

This is the init function:

```
init {
        mRecyclerView.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this)
        mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener)
    }
```

and have a `companion object` to add it to the recyclerView:

```
companion object {

        fun addTo(view: RecyclerView): ItemClickSupport {
            var support: ItemClickSupport? = view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support) as ItemClickSupport
            if (support == null) {
                support = ItemClickSupport(view)
            }
            return support
        }
}
```

When I run my app and try to add the clickListener to the recyclerView, I get a

> Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.dancam.subscriptions.Support.ItemClickSupport
>                         at com.dancam.subscriptions.Support.ItemClickSupport$Companion.addTo(ItemClickSupport.kt:80)
>                         at com.dancam.subscriptions.AddSubscription.AddSubscription.onCreate(AddSubscription.kt:79)

with the first error pointing to this line in the `addTo` function:

```
var support: ItemClickSupport? = view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support) as ItemClickSupport
```

and the second one to this in my `main_activity`:

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView!!).setOnItemClickListener(
                object: ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener {
                    override fun onItemClicked(recyclerView: RecyclerView, position: Int, v: View ) {
                        ...
                    }
                })
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Cast the `getTag` result using `as ItemClickSupport?` instead?

Comment: You need to use `as?` instead of `as`. Using `as` results in force typecasting like `(ItemClickSupport)null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Kotlin reference (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html):

> **"Unsafe" cast operator**
>
> Usually, the cast operator throws an exception if the cast is not
>   possible. Thus, we call it unsafe. The unsafe cast in Kotlin is done
>   by the infix operator as (see operator precedence):
>
> ```
> val x: String = y as String
> ```
>
> Note that null cannot be cast to String as this type is not nullable,
>   i.e. if y is null, the code above throws an exception. In order to
>   match Java cast semantics we have to have nullable type at cast right
>   hand side, like:
>
> ```
> val x: String? = y as String?
> ```

You can also use the so called "Safe" (nullable) cast operator which, as far as I know, is equivalent:

```
val x: String? = y as? String
```

So in your specific case:

```
var support: ItemClickSupport? = view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support) as ItemClickSupport?
```

or

```
var support: ItemClickSupport? = view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support) as? ItemClickSupport
```